# Copy two dimensional dynamic array(pointers) to a static array using memcpy

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, memcpy

I've 2D arrays as below,

```
float** src;
```

which is filled with some values.

```
float des[x][x];
```

`x` is equal to the number of rows in `src` array.

So basically i want to generate a static 2D array from a dynamic 2D array.
I tried to use `memcpy(&des, src, x)`, But it gives wrong result.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Need copy each rows.

Comment: `float**` is not contiguous in memory. You can't use memcpy only once. Try to understand what `**` means. You can do this with memcpy `x` times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your `memcpy`:

### 1. `src` rows are not necessarily continuous

Consider:

```
#define x 2
float src_row_0[x] = { 0.0f, 0.1f };
float src_row_1[x] = { 1.0f, 1.1f };
float * src_rows[x] = { src_row_0, src_row_1 };
float ** src = src_rows;
```

There is no guarantee that rows are next to each other in memory. So you cannot copy bytes with single `memcpy`. Same applies even if you allocated `src`rows with `malloc`.

You'll need to copy each row separately.

### 2. Size `x` is not enough to copy all bytes

`memcpy` copies number of bytes, not number of elements. Single `float` variable is usually more than 1 byte in size. Simply passing `x` to `memcpy` is not enough. You'll need to multiply each number of items by size of an single element.

### Fixing the copy

Corrected copy would look something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<x; ++i) {
    memcpy(&dst[i], src[i], x * sizeof(float));
}
```

[Example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/YuWsrD)

Answer (score 1):

Well, 2D array element's are stored in memory in a row,
|x| == memory cell

> 1.row |x|x|x|x|x|x| 2.row |x|x|x|x|x|x| 3.row |x|x|x|x|x|x|

while every pointer of array of pointer can point on completely different address in memory. For example first pointer points on array on adress 100, second points on adress 248, third on array on adress 2.

> 3.row |x|x|x|x|x|x| |?|?|?| 1.row |x|x|x|x|x|x| |?|?|?|?| 2.row |x|x|x|x|x|x|

So you could use memcpy on every row of arrays separately, or copy them element by element.

Hope it helps.